# jQuery - Draggable, drag the container when child is dragged

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make some nice stuff with the Draggable library in jQuery.

I wan't to make a small area of a div to be the "thing" you have to drag, to start the draggable action, and then move the whole div, and not only the small area. But I can't figure out how to do this?

Basic: Small box is dragged, make the whole parent div dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle

Comment: i think you are right. Gosh.. It's early. Sorry for not reading it already:o) well, thanks :)